# Simulate Wind in Gazebo - physics_msgs

Tags: control, quadcopter, ros, simulation, gazebo

I am trying to simulate a drone inside an environment with constant wind. I have found a good plugin (link below) and I have done the following to integrate this plugin in my system:

1. include the gazebo_wind_plugin.cpp file in my src folder
2. include the header file (gazebo_wind_plugin.h) in the include folder
3. edit the CmakeLists.txt to include this plugin

https://github.com/PX4/PX4-SITL_gazebo/blob/master/src/gazebo_wind_plugin.cpp

However, I get errors during `catkin_make` showing the following:

[image]

How should I install/integrate `physics_msgs`? Kindly advice if any other issue is present.

Comment: Please edit your post to have a copy and paste of the error, not a screen shot. That's not searchable or able to be copy and pasted. Please also include the full output with the input command, with just a snippet it's hard to confirm it is the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to compile these files with your plugin. You should include the already existing `wind` plugin in to your world file. [Check this example file and how you should use the wind plugin](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/wind.sdf#L364-L403). The Gazebo physics will be on charge of applying the wind to your drone.